# Adding all the items in <select> list to a model attribute

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC form where there are two select boxes.
One box is pre-populated and the other one is initially empty.
I use JQuery to move items from the pre-populated list to the empty one and I'd like to take all the items from the list into a model attribute.
Is there any way to do this using Spring form? 
When the form submit happens, the model attribute that is bound to the select list seems to be null since none of the list items are actually 'selected'.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You will need to submit those items somehow.  I see several options

- use jQuery to select all the items before submitting the form
- use jQuery to submit the form and add all the items to the submitted form manually
- when adding to the empty form also add to a hidden input field

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I did use a hidden field to store String values of the id fields. But then, I need to convert them to a list of objects after the submit. I was hoping for an option where I could bind actual objects to the model attribute instead of String.